# Split pandas dataframe based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following data:

```py
test_data = pd.DataFrame({
    "col": ["wall", "wall", "lamp", "lamp", "desk", "desk", "desk",
            "mug", "floor"],
    })
```

I would like to create three (two for edge cases) datasets, based on a particular value within a given column (in this case `col`).

For example, if the value `col = lamp` was given I would expect :

```
df 1
| col   |
|:------|
| wall  |
| wall  |

df 2
| col   |
|:------|
| lamp  |
| lamp  |

df 3
| col   |
|:------|
| desk  |
| desk  |
| desk  |
| mug   |
| floor |
```

I've tried using the following:

```py
match_str = "mug"

match_start, match_end = (
    test_data["col"].eq(match_str).loc[lambda x: x].index.min(),
    test_data["col"].eq(match_str).loc[lambda x: x].index.max(),
)

df1_filt = pd.Series(test_data.index).lt(match_start)
df2_filt = pd.Series(test_data.index).between(match_start, match_end)
df3_filt = pd.Series(test_data.index).gt(match_end)

df1, df2, df3 = (
    test_data.loc[df1_filt],
    test_data.loc[df2_filt],
    test_data.loc[df3_filt],
)
```

Which seems to handle the requirement - it makes the assumption that `col` is ordered, but if it wasn't ordered there wouldn't be any sense to this operation anyway.

Comment: So if your solution works, what do you need help with exactly? What's your question? Maybe you want to ask if there's a built-in way to do this? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: FWIW, instead of `.min()` and `.max()`, you can do `[[0, -1]]`.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh from end of the post : "_  makes the assumption that col is ordered, but if it wasn't ordered there wouldn't be any sense to this operation anyway_"

Answer (score 1):

This is like the behaviour of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), right? We need to group things that are next to each other, and depending on whether they are equal to the search value. So an imitation of Python's groupby in pandas is "diff-ne(0)-cumsum" idiom, so here we go:

```py
In [301]: df
Out[301]:
     col
0   wall
1   wall
2   lamp
3   lamp
4   desk
5   desk
6   desk
7    mug
8  floor

In [302]: [sub_frame
           for _, sub_frame in df.groupby(df.col.eq("lamp").diff().ne(0).cumsum())]
Out[302]:
[    col
 0  wall
 1  wall,
     col
 2  lamp
 3  lamp,
      col
 4   desk
 5   desk
 6   desk
 7    mug
 8  floor]
```

It gave a list of 3 dataframes: *before* the "lamp stream", *during* the lamp stream, and *after*. This will respect the edge cases as well.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you see yourself trying to split something into an unknown number of variables dynamically it should probably set off a red flag.  I would suggest creating a group flag in the data set, then using that to groupby or iterate over.

```
import pandas as pd
test_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col": ["wall", "wall", "lamp", "lamp", "desk", "desk", "desk", "mug", "floor"],
    }
)

test_data['group'] = test_data['col'].eq('mug').diff().ne(0).cumsum()
print(test_data)
```

Output

```
     col  group
0   wall      1
1   wall      1
2   lamp      1
3   lamp      1
4   desk      1
5   desk      1
6   desk      1
7    mug      2
8  floor      3
```

If you MUST split them for whatever reason, at least use a dictionary to store them so you can handle various numbers of dataframes coming back.

```
import pandas as pd
    test_data = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "col": ["wall", "wall", "lamp", "lamp", "desk", "desk", "desk", "mug", "floor"],
        }
    )

output = {group:data for group,data in test_data.groupby(test_data['col'].eq('mug').diff().ne(0).cumsum())}

print(output[2])
```

Results

```
   col
7  mug
```

Comment: "... set off a red flag" yeah makes sense - i have some long data and the ordering of the data dictates how particular outputs are made - so i need to reorder subsets of the long data. The example from this post might have been a subset of the long data, and there could be several of these within the full data set :S

Answer (score 0):

```
match_str = 'lamp'
#breaking point
bp = test_data.loc[test_data['col'] == match_str, :].index

#before bp(smaller than bk's head)
b_bp = test_data.index < bp[0]

#after bp(greater than bk's tail)
a_bp = test_data.index >bp[-1]
```

```
df_1 = test_data.iloc[b_bp]
df_1
###
    col
0  wall
1  wall
```

```
df2 = test_data.iloc[bp]
df2
###
    col
2  lamp
3  lamp
```

```
df3 = test_data.iloc[a_bp]
df3
###
     col
4   desk
5   desk
6   desk
7    mug
8  floor
```